# 401 Unauthorized after OAuth 2 authentication

Tags: 401, oauth, aad

I am developing a native app (WinInet/C++) and after completing OAuth2 as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) and getting auth token, try to send any request to my SharePoint but get 401.

The site is SharePoint online (like https://mycompany-my.sharepoint.com), my app is registered in Azure AD.

401 response asks for X-Forms auth in the header, while I need OAuth since it has long-living token, allows several users being logged-in on the same application, gives more control on revocation and refreshing of the token.

[image]

Comment: Did you gave proper App Permission

Comment: If you mean in Azure portal, yes, it's set to full access (set it for testing purpose). But I didn't register the app on SharePoint server specifically since expected usage is to run on customer's servers where I cannot register my app on every server.

Comment: No, I mean Azure API. If you are going use graph API then you need to register Azure API in azure active directory blade

Comment: I am not using graph API - I use some mix of CSOM and other older API since some customers still have old SP on-premise/local versions and I wouldn't like to have several implementations - old and new-like. I didn't really get what is registering Azure API in AAD blad :( How can I register API? In general, I followed steps described by the link in my question

Comment: Firstly, **The site is SharePoint online (like https://mycompany-my.sharepoint.com), my app is registered in Azure AD.** It's a Onedrive URL, not a SharePoint site URL in Office 365.

Comment: Therefore, Did you check this app in any other SharePoint site?

Comment: Please! check this two Reference and Provide your inputs: [Call SharePoint Online with same AAD token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791232/call-sharepoint-online-with-same-aad-token) && [Discovery Service REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/discovery-service-rest-operations)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know it's OneDrive but it also has SP running, and all works if I use any other auth method!

Comment: Can we create a Chat room and you can tell me your availability and then we discuss at that time? I have a few doubts.

Comment: we can though I don't know how :) I'm usually available at UTC 7:30-18:00

Comment: Have you got an invitation?

Comment: I guess not :( can we talk somehow else? like email amykhailiuk@gmail.com or skype:amykhailiuk

Answer (score 0):

I have put it as answer as in comments I cannot add image.

Now over to your question, Documentation link which you gave clearly mention that you to register app on Azure. Please read documentation properly. If you can't then let me know I will come on chat and help you out.[image]

Comment: I have done it. If didn't I wouldn't be able to get auth token. But as I wrote, I do get auth token but it does not work with SP server

Comment: go to http://jwt.ms and past your auth token and send us screen shot of the result

Comment: sorry, "send us" - whom "us"? cannot put screenshot here

Comment: Us me and other people who can help. To put screen shot edit your original question with screen shot

Comment: Did you resolve the issue

Comment: No - why? It still returns token normally but fails to authorize with it :(

Comment: As I told you, use jwt.ms which will decrypt your auth code and it will help to  understand why it is not working. I want to check audience and scope

Comment: my bad I did not see your snap shot.

Comment: How do you send request through REST API or GRAPH API ?

Comment: I wrote in the question comments: SOAP/SCOM + some REST + FrontPage... The first call which I do and it fails with 401 is SOAP `WebUrlFromPageUrlResponse`

Comment: sorry, just `WebUrlFromPageUrl`